# update and delete is not working vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

im having a problem in my codes there's no error showing up and when i press the button nothing happens this is the code im using first one is the update button

```
Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click
 Try
                con.Open()
                With cmd
                    .Connection = con
                    .CommandText = ("Update TBL_EMPLOYEE MiddleName='" & txtMiddleName.Text & "',LastName='" & txtLastName.Text & "', Gender='" & txtGender.Text & "',Age='" & txtupAge.Text & "' ,Address='" & txtupAddress.Text & "', Position='" & txtPos.Text & "',BirthDate='" & Bdate.Text & "' where [FirstName]=@FirstName ")
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("FirstName", (txtFirstName.Text))
                    .ExecuteNonQuery()
                    .Dispose()
                    txtFirstName.Text = ""
                    txtMiddleName.Text = ""
                    txtLastName.Text = ""
                    txtGender.Text = ""
                    txtContactNumber.Text = ""
                    txtupAge.Text = ""
                    txtupAddress.Text = ""
                    txtPos.Text = ""
                    Bdate.Text = ""
                    PictureBox2.Image = Nothing


                    MsgBox("Product Updated", vbInformation, "Information Message")
                    datagridshow()


                End With
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
        End Sub
```

there's no error showing up in the code and nothing happening when i pressed the button and same with my delete button

```
  Private Sub btnDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
        Try
            con.Open()
            With cmd
                .Connection = cn
                .CommandText = "DELETE * from [TBL_EMPLOYEE]  where FirstName='" & DataGridView2.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value.ToString & "' "
                .ExecuteNonQuery()
                .Dispose()
                .Parameters.Clear()
                txtFirstName.Text = ""
                txtMiddleName.Text = ""
                txtLastName.Text = ""
                txtGender.Text = ""
                txtContactNumber.Text = ""
                txtupAge.Text = ""
                txtupAddress.Text = ""
                txtPos.Text = ""
                Bdate.Text = ""
                PictureBox2.Image = Nothing

                MsgBox("Employee Deleted", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
                datagridshow()
            End With
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try

    End Sub
```

there's no error and nothing happen also here 
this is the form load i am using.

```
 Dim str As String
        str = ("Server=LOCALHOST\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Payroll;Trusted_Connection=True;")
        cn = New SqlConnection(Str)
        cn.Open()
```

Comment: Start by removing the empty try/catch. This is hiding all errors. Also, you were doing well with the AddWithValue, I suggest you add this for all values instead of concatenating.

Comment: Before another line of code you need to read about, understand and start using parameterized queries. Your code is wide open to sql injection. My friend bobby tables love this kind of stuff. http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: `there's no error showing`  Of course not!  Your code is eating any and all exceptions.  Stop that!

Comment: And your code has an anti-pattern I call try/squelch. You use a try catch but in your catch you don't do anything. All that manages to do it capture and error and silently throw it away. You would be better off having no try catch if you don't do anything with the error.

Comment: An empty Catch is the devil's workshop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your UPDATE is missing the SET keyword, and your DELETE has a * that shouldn't be there.

Comment: While this is true I can't give a +1 without mention of how awful not using parameters is or the empty catch. This is more like a comment than an answer.